# Java switch statement going straight to default

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a switch statement to calculate how much a patient owes on their insurance but for some reason it always charges them the default price of 45$. If they're not using any of the three options their price is 45$ but even if I say I'm using US Insurance or Mountain Health, it says the price is 45$. Any idea why it's not working?

Also, is there a way to ignore whether or not the user uses capital letters or not so they would get the same result if they typed "US INSURANCE", "us insurance", or "US Insurance"?

```
    int charge;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("What is the name of your insurance? ");
    Insurance = kb.nextLine();

    switch (Insurance) {

        case "Mountain Health":
            charge= 30; 
            break;

        case "US Insurance":
            charge= 40;
            break;

        case "Blue Insurance": 
            charge= 45;
            break;

        default:
            price = 45;
    }
    System.out.println("Your charge is " + charge + "$.");
```

Comment: whats the type of insurance, could you show where you declare it

Comment: @Sudakatux It's a `String`, otherwise OP gets a compilation error.

Comment: yeah noticed just after hitting enter. :P

Comment: I would add a `System.out.println(Insurance);` above the switch (or debug it), and look at that to compare. Posting the output of it would help us help you. Also switch is case sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

Match the full case with the compared String

```
switch (insurance.toUppercase()) {
...

case "MOUNTAIN HEALTH":
....
```

Comment: @Aaron or uppercase ;)

Comment: No need for a locale?

Answer (score 1):

If none of the options in the switch case are met, your code will go to the default case.  The variable charge is not used anymore and you instead are printing the charge.

You should remove empty spaces and make comparisons to lower/uppercase:

```
    switch (insurance.toLowerCase().trim()) { 
        case "mountain health":
            charge = 30;
            break;
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to put the options in a class (I believe this is the best practice):

```
public class InsuranceTypes {

   public static String MOUNTAIN_HEALTH = "MOUNTAIN HEALTH";
   public static String US_INSURANCE = "US INSURANCE"
   ...
}
```

And in the usage:

```
switch (insurance.toUppercase()) {
...

case InsuranceTypes.MOUNTAIN_HEALTH:
...
```

That helps preventing from making a typo in the case statements.

Comment: Possible, but since you are receiving the input as String you will have to convert the enum somehow to be able to use it in the switch and have it correlate with the input string (enum can't contain spaces, the input can.. etc.)

Comment: just ovverride the toString()... but not so immediate as you point.